# tableView editTriggers только для одной колонки

Tags: qt

Как разрешить редактирование по (submit) только для одной колонки таблицы?

```
setTable("orders");
setRelation(fieldIndex("worker_id"),QSqlRelation("workers","worker_id","name"));
setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
select();

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui->tableView->hideColumn(0);
ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("worker_id"),new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView));
```

на данный момент связи работают. Редактирование невозможно. Если ставлю AllEditTriggers то можно все поля редактировать. Из worker_is "комбобокс" не выпадает ((( но если ставлю туда айдишник то подтаскивает имя.
p.s. как разрешить редактирование только одной колонки worker_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно унаследовать модель своей и переопределить метод `flags()`:

```
class Model : public QSqlTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT

    Model(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QSqlTableModel(parent) {}

    Qt::ItemFlags Model::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if(index.column() == fieldIndex("worker_id")) {
            return QSqlQueryModel::flags(index)
                | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
        }

        return QSqlQueryModel::flags(index);
    }
}
```

Можно создать делегат и установить его в виджет-представление:

```
class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Delegate(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

        virtual QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent
            , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
            , const QModelIndex &index) const {

            const QSqlTableModel *model
                = qobject_cast<const QSqlTableModel*>(index.model());

            if(model != Q_NULLPTR) {
                if(index.column() == model->fieldIndex("worker_id"))
                    return Q_NULLPTR;
            }

            return QStyledItemDelegate
                ::createEditor(parent, option, index);
        }
};
```

Comment: есть ли возможность совмещения работы стота dubleclicked со всем этим(делигатом)???

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: ну  я слот на tableView поставил открытие окна для редактирования по двойному клику on_tableView_doubleClicked, ну и чекбокс тоже открывается если в ячейку два раза тыкать (

Comment: Поведением на активацию редактирования можно управлять посредством [этого метода](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop).

Answer (score 0):

crmmodel.h (далее рефракторинг->виртульные методы->flags())

```
class CRMModel : public QSqlRelationalTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    CRMModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase());

private:
    int m_value;

public:
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
```

crmmodel.cpp

```
CRMModel::CRMModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db)
        : QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent, db)
    { 
        setTable("orders");
        setRelation(fieldIndex("worker_id"),QSqlRelation("workers","worker_id","name"));
        setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
        select();
    }

    Qt::ItemFlags CRMModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        if(index.column() == fieldIndex("name"))
        {
             return QSqlQueryModel::flags(index)| Qt::ItemIsEditable;
        }
             return QSqlQueryModel::flags(index);
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp(кусок кода)

```
model = new CRMModel(this,baze);

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->tableView->hideColumn(0);
  //  ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(model->fieldIndex("worker_id"),new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView));
```

запускает. ошибок нету. тока чтобы можно было редактировать надо отключать слот doubleClicked.(у меня там окно для редактирование открывалось по двойному щелчку).